# geodango form with geometry field and leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, geodjango, django

i use geodjango and leaflet and i want to create a django form where including geometry field with map widget  (the user must to put in leaflet map) like as django admin page . i try to follow this [example](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/django-leaflet/latest/django-leaflet.pdf)

but in html page dont show me the form ,any idea ?

here the code :

urls.py

```
url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='home'),
```

models.py

```
from djgeojson.fields import PolygonField
from django.db import models

class MushroomSpot(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    geom = PolygonField()

    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from leaflet.forms.fields import PolygonField
from mushrooms.models import MushroomSpot


class WeatherStationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    geom = PolygonField()
    class Meta:
        model = MushroomSpot
        fields = ('name', 'geom')
```

html page :

```
{% load leaflet_tags %}
<html>
<head>
{% leaflet_js plugins="forms" %}
    {% leaflet_css plugins="forms" %}
</head>
<body>
<h1>Edit {{ object }}</h1>
<form action="POST">
{{ WeatherStationForm }}
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not initialize your `WeatherStationForm` within the view.
To do so, you have to inherit from `TemplateView` and override `get_context` function:

**Example (not tested):**

```
# Normally in views.py

class MapView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context(self, **kwargs):
        context = {'weatherstation': WeatherStationForm()}
        return context
```

Now, `WeatherStationForm` is initialized and you can access it in your index.html template via `{{ weatherstation }}`:

```
{% load leaflet_tags %}
<html>
<head>
{% leaflet_js plugins="forms" %}
    {% leaflet_css plugins="forms" %}
</head>
<body>
<h1>Edit {{ object }}</h1>
<form action="POST">
{{ weatherstation }}
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally your `urls.py`:

```
from views import MapView

url(r'^$', MapView.as_view(), name='home')
```

Note: Urls-definition has changed to `path()`in Django 2.0 - maybe you should update your django version first...